# Unit Testing Controller for HTTP and HTTPS in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, https, controller

I need to generate a selection of unit tests to ensure that the controllers will only work with HTTPS and then generate some negative tests for HTTP.

But how do you test a controller to ensure that it will only work with HTTPS?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what are you asking for a controller, because in theory it applies SOC so you're going to be able to test the mechaniscs of the controller but not the environment itself, that goes beyond the controller responsability. I think it envoles the fact that you need to focus on routing maybe.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a test that make it runs trying to use https protocol, and some that use other protocols (http,ftp...). check that https works and other are refused. Please give more details if you can.